# postfix rewriting sender with generic & header_check

Tags: postfix, email

I want to rewrite all sender addresses **@example.com to newsender@example.org** (to one static outgoing address) but I also want to have the original address added as the `reply-to`. I can do either individually with the generic file and header_checks files respectively but as the generic file seems to be used first, I lose the original sender. Did I miss something from [postfix rewrite documentation](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html)?

It would be OK if the envelope sender had something like **original+mydomain.com@newsenderdom.com** as long as `From:` header is **newsender@newsenderdom.com**. Any ideas?

If there is an easy solution in Qmail then that would also be an option!

Answer (score 4):

After many hours searching and several posts (here and elsewhere) saying it isn't possible without a milter or with instructions that didn't work for me (like above), success!

At least with my testing on my setup, you cannot use smtp_generic_maps because that seems to be executed *before* other checks/rewrites. If you use sender_canonical_maps, however, then that seems to get executed *after* checks like header_checks. So, you can simply have the following in `main.cf`:

```
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Contents of files

/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps:

```
@example.com    user@example.org
```

/etc/postfix/header_checks:

```
/^From:(.*)$/   PREPEND Reply-To:$1
```

And run `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps`

Restart postfix `service postfix restart`

And you're away laughing :-). This adds the expected Reply-to: whateverwasthere@example.com header and changes both the envelope & header from to user@example.org.

Comment: +1 Congratulations :) Sorry for misdirection solution :(. Anyway your conclusion about why `smtp_generic_maps` rewriting `Reply-To` wasn't right. [This page](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#overview) stated that generic invoked right by smtp process, **right before delivering email and after other rewrite rules**. Unfortunately, the default behavior of [generic](http://www.postfix.org/generic.5.html) process is also rewrite all header of email *(including old From and new Reply-To header)*

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work on my system:
in my sender_canonical_maps i have __/.*/ sender@somehost.de__, my header_checks matches your suggestion and still the reply-to address gets replaced by sender@somehost.de

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there are two goals here:

1. Append original sender to `Reply-To` header.
2. Rewrite the sender into static value.

For first goal, using [smtpd_sender_restriction](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) + [access maps](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) should do the trick. Specify this paramater in `main.cf`

```
smtpd_sender_restriction = check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/append_replyto.pcre
```

The content of `/etc/postfix/append_replyto.pcre`

```
/(.*)/  PREPEND Reply-To:$1
```

The map file will match all sender and append the it in Reply-To header.

---

<strike>The second goal is achieved with [smtp_generic_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_generic_maps)</strike>. Whoops... looks like I'm missing a bit piece of [generic](http://www.postfix.org/generic.5.html) behavior. It will rewrite **all header (in From/Reply-To/other) and envelope**.

> The generic(5) mapping affects  both  **message  header  addresses  (i.e. addresses  that  appear inside messages)** and message envelope addresses (for example, the addresses that are used in SMTP protocol commands).

For working solution, see the solution from the OP :)

Comment: Are you sure about this @masegaloeh? I am still getting newsender@example.org in the reply-to. I am running a standard ubuntu 12.04 (postfix 2.9.6) install. The only thing I changed was using regexp instead of pcre as pcre doesn't seem to be enabled by default.